# Visual Basic Settings File

Tags: vb.net, settings

I am working on a visual basic project where I have my own classes of objects. I would like to save them into the settings file. When I go to look up the type in the settings file, I cannot find a way to declare a setting as one of my own classes. I assume that this is not possible. Also, I cannot save arrays to a single setting file correct? For each element in an array(assuming the type is a type that is allowed in a setting), I need to save each element to its own setting, right?

Thanks.

JD

Comment: Project -> Properties -> Settings.  To actually save the object states, you probably want serialization though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.  You must add a Class Library project to your solution that contains the Public Class.  Right-click your EXE project and choose Add Reference, select your class library project.  Ensure everything is built.

You can now click the arrow on the Type column in the Settings designer page and choose Browse.  Your class library project appears in the list, select the class.

Comment: I created a class library project just to test this, and I can't find this in the references. I created the class library and saved it. I then went back to my original project, right clicked on the project name and clicked "Add Reference." A window popped up with tabs: "Assemblies" "Solution" "COM" and "Browse". There is nothing under "Solution" tab. I presume that is where it would be right? Am I looking in the right place? I am running Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Your class library project should be in the same solution to make this easy.  You'd pick it from the Solution tab.  The not-recommended way is to use Browse and pick the DLL that was built by your other project.

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. But there is nothing in the solution tab. Now when you say add a Class Library, are you talking about adding a class file or like starting another project inside the current project, compile it, and then select from that class?

Comment: You are getting hung on basics, sounds like you've never created a solution with more than one project.  Just google it, "vb.net add project to solution" to find a tutorial.